# Javascript Promises: fetch .then retrieving [[PromiseValue]]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, request-promise

I'm trying to retrieve the `[[PromiseValue]]` of a Promise.
My function currently returns a Promise instead and the value I want `myFunction` to return is the value stored in `[[PromiseValue]]` of the returned Promise.

This returns a Promise.

```
myFunction(){
    return fetch("/api")
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            return json;
        })
}
```

I tried this code, but when I print the data in console, it prints the correct value, but the returned value is undefined.

```
myFunction(){
    return fetch("/api")
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            return json;
        })
        .then(data => {
            const stringData = data.toString();
            console.log(stringData); // prints the correct string
            return stringData; // returns undefined
        })
}
```

How would I make my function return the value stored in `[[PromiseValue]]` as a String?
Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: I think you may need to use `await` to "wait" for the value to be resolved. `Promise.prototype.then` still returns a `Promise`, so your function is returning a `Promise`.

Comment: What is `last` you haven't defined it in this code which is why it is returning `undefined`. Or is there more code than this?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Could you give a short example for using ```await``` to return the value as a string? I tried using it but it gave me error saying await is used outside of async function..

Comment: It's weird post the calling function code also or where you are catching the response post that code

Comment: @theWellHopeErr Sorry! I meant to return stringData. I edited my question above.

Comment: @Navitas28 So what I tried at first is not to return the fetch call but just to have the fetch call itself inside the function, but the return value just becomes `undefined` in that case..

Comment: @CS_Newbie You need to `return` in both places. The code as you currently have it in the question works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function cannot return the `PromiseValue` directly, since `fetch` works asynchronously. It will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will eventually resolve to that value.

Using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), what you could do is:

```js
async function myFunction() {
  const res = await fetch('/api');
  const json = await res.json();
  return JSON.stringify(json);
  // json.toString() is a bit weird … but do as you please
  // I'd return the json and parse it at the callsite.
}

const result = await myFunction();
```

(note: this snippet requires a modern engine which supports top-level `await`. Latest chrome will work just fine.)

Comment: I need to this data inside a different function, so I tried calling the line `const result = await myFunction()` in some other function and it caused me error `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: Actually, I fixed the code so now the code runs, but the result is still a Promise not a string value....

Comment: Well, the error pretty much says it: in order to use `awaít`, you have to use the `async` keyword infront of your `function` declaration (like in the code I posted).
Async behavior is **everywhere** in modern JS … and I know, building stuff is always more fun than the dry basics, but I highly recommend you take the time to understand the Promise/async-await fundamentals before advancing on your JS adventure :)